# BootStrap Tab Content Work Only In localhost

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

503/5000
I am experiencing a very strange problem in my code. I programmed my website on localhost using xampp. Everything works perfectly as it should be. This morning I bought a vps where I installed ubuntu server and apache and loaded it all. Database calls work everything works except the bootstrap content tab. When I click on the next tab the tab is not changed by adding only to the end of the link the id of the clicked tab. What may have happened?

Comment: Sounds like your Bootstrap JS isn't getting loaded...perhaps it's hard coded to the http://localhost location?

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Post a [mcve] please. Also, what does `503/5000` mean in your question?